# IPTable rules to restrict eth1 access to ports 80 and 443

Tags: networking, tcp, iptables

I have a service listening to customer traffic on ports 80 and 443 of eth1. The servers hosting my service also host other admin/privileged access content on eth0 and localhost

I am trying to setup iptable rules to lock down eth1 on servers which is on same network as clients (block things like ssh through eth1/ accessing internal services running on port 9904 etc.) I also want to make sure that the rules dont forbid regular access to eth1:80 and eth1:443. I have come up with below rules but wanted to review with iptable gurus on possible issues with this rule.

```
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -j DROP
```

- Do the rules above suffice
- How does above differ from the rules found when googling

> ```
> -P INPUT ACCEPT
> -P FORWARD ACCEPT
> -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
> -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
> -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
> -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j DROP
> -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -j ACCEPT
> -A INPUT -i eth1 -j DROP
> ```

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions. You will find iptable gurus at serverfault.com

Comment: thanks i got this answered in http://serverfault.com/questions/834534/iptable-rules-to-restrict-eth1-access-to-ports-80-and-443 for people who might have the same question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks i got this answered in https://serverfault.com/questions/834534/iptable-rules-to-restrict-eth1-access-to-ports-80-and-443 , adding it here for completeness

> The first set of rules first allow all incoming packets on your ports
>   80 and 443. Then it drops ALL other incoming packets (except those
>   already accepted).
>
> The second set of rules first allow all incoming packets on ports 80
>   and 443. Then it drops incoming connections (excluding 80 and 443 that
>   are already accepted), which are packets with only the SYN flag set.
>   Then it allows all incoming packets.
>
> The difference here is what happens to your OUTGOING connections. In
>   the first ruleset, if you attempt to connect to another server, any
>   packets that server sends in response will be dropped so you will
>   never receive any data. In the second case, those packets will be
>   allowed since the first packet from the remote server will have both
>   SYN and ACK set and therefore pass the SYN test, and any following
>   packets will not have SYN set at all, and therefore pass the test.
>
> This has been traditionally done using conntrack which requires the
>   kernel to keep track of every connection in the firewall, with a
>   command like
>
> -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
>
> that matches the incoming packet either to an existing connection, or
>   a connection related to some other existing connection (eg FTP data
>   connections). If you aren't using FTP or other protocols that use
>   multiple random ports, then the second ruleset achieves basically the
>   same result without the overhead of tracking and inspecting these
>   connections.